# swagger multiple versions in path

Tags: java, spring, swagger

I have the following spring get mapping (`org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping`) in a controller:

```
@GetMapping("/v{version:[1-2]}/something/{id}")
```

I want to be able to access the two versions of the api in swagger. This is my swagger config:

```
@Bean
public Docket v1(SwaggerProperties swaggerProperties) {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .groupName("V1")
        .select()
            .paths(regex("/v1/.*")).build()     
}

@Bean
public Docket v2(SwaggerProperties swaggerProperties) {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .groupName("V2")
        .select()
            .paths(regex("/v2/.*")).build()   
}
```

This does not work, the only thing I can see in swagger when I remove the `paths` selector is:

```
/v{version}/something/{id}
```

And I would like to see:

```
/v1/something/{id}
```

When selecting the `V1` group in the swagger group selector:
[image: swagger group selector]
And this when selecting `V2`:

```
/v2/something/{id}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you might need to implement custom [PathProvider](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.6.0/index.html?springfox/documentation/PathProvider.html) to unwrap the mapping path `"/v{version:[1-2]}/something/{id}"` into particular one in Docket like that:

```
//in Docket
.pathProvider(new ParticularVersionPathProvider("v1"))

...
class ParticularVersionPathProvider extends AbstractPathProvider {
   ...
   private String version;
   BasePathAwareRelativePathProvider(String version){
       this.version = version;
   }

   @Override
   public String getOperationPath(String operationPath) {
       //very schematically
       return operationPath.replace("v{version}",version);
   }
}
```

[see this complete example](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/963#issuecomment-198551416)

Comment: Thanks but I still have the same problem the regex does not seem to pick up the right version, removing the regex I have the following `/v{version}/something/{id}` so it is like I need swagger to replace `{version}` with 1 or 2 in the config if that is possible

Comment: The only way it works is with `@GetMapping({"/v1/something/{id}", "/v2/something/{id}"})` which is a pain because it involves a lot of duplication for future versions

Comment: General usecase is that you usually have @GetMapping("/v1/some") on one method and @GetMapping("/v2/some") on totally different. It sounds strange to me, that you're going to have single piece of code handling different versions of your APIs, including further versions. Is that even necessary to version such endpoint at all?

Comment: That's true, but for all other methods where there is no change I want them to work weather you request `/v1/something` or `/v2/something`, I don't want the clients to get a 404 for 99% of the methods when requesting the version 2 (or the version 1)

Comment: Awesome, works fine now thanks to your last update to the question, the `operationPath` turns out to be `/v{version}/something/{id}` so we need to replace `v{version}` instead